# How to use merge function in asp.net-vb?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, crystal-reports, merge, dataset

I'm making a report using `crystal report` and I want to get the `total amount` from a `data adapter` so I have two queries. What I want to do is I want to **merge** the `two datasets` to make it one statement when filling in the crystal report. But it seems that `merging` datasets is not working for me. I'm using `sql server` for my backend. Any other approach? Here is my code:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think using 2 DataSets is necessary to accomplish this. Try to do it with only the 1st query/DataSet.

Typical way to display total amount of data in crystal report is using **Summary Field**. Specify which column to aggregate and the aggregate function of choice (`SUM` function in this case) :

### Steps

[image]

[image]

### Result

[image]

**[Source : [http://csharp.net-informations.com](http://csharp.net-informations.com/crystal-reports/csharp-crystal-reports-summary-field.htm)]**

Comment: the thing is that `Calculate this summary` selection only contains **maximum**,**minimum**,**count**, **distinct count**,**mode**, and so on. It doesn't have a **sum** value

Comment: If I don't misunderstand this question, looking at your query to get the summary, I think you need to choose **sum** in "*Calculate this summary*" selection, and select `totalamt` field to summarize. Why looking for *count value*?

Comment: I don't currently have teamviewer. How about upload some screenshot?

Comment: http://postimg.org/image/xxkarhdjt/ Check the link. Here is the only option in my _Calculate this summary field_

Comment: no should work on either winform or asp.net. I suspect it because your column type is not *summable*, for example of type varchar/string.

Comment: So how can I make it? I tried to convert it to currency or integer but I doesn't work. It always sending me an error

Comment: check [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28899/Crystal-Report-with-DataSet-and-DataTable-using-C), make sure DataTable column to be summarized is of type number (int/decimal/double/etc).